# Django login form error styling

Tags: python, django

I am attempting to create a custom login page for users in django. Here is the template I placed under `registration/login.html`

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container login-container">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
    </form>
    <br>
    <p><strong>-- OR --</strong></p>
    ....
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is how the page is reached" `server/urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
...
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
...
```

My issue is that I have no control over the way the errors or form objects are displayed and can find nothing in the documentation. If you know how I can control how the form is rendered that would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Here is the code I used for the solution and a link to the documentation

**Custom form rendering**

```
<h2>Login</h2>
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
{% endif %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ form.username.label_tag }} {{ form.username }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.password.label_tag }} {{ form.password }}</p>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
</form>
```

Detailed docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views